# laravel view with a variable

Tags: php, laravel, variables, view

```
    public function getValues(Request $request){
    $typ=$request->get('typ');
    $stellentyp=$request->get('stellentyp');
    $bereich=$request->get('bereich');
    return view('test.result',['typ' => $typ, 'stellentyp', $stellentyp, 'bereich', $bereich]);
}
```

this is my controller function now.
Is it possible to get this view:

```
return view('test.$stellentyp',['typ' => $typ, 'stellentyp', $stellentyp, 'bereich', $bereich]);
```

i want that the user can select the "stellentyp" and then the view with that "stellentyp" should be shown

i dont know if its possible in laravel , but i know its posible in php

thank you! :)

Comment: AJAX would work for you.

Comment: This is also possible in laravel to return a view with it's parameters inside array like you mentioned.

Comment: Use `"test.$stellentyp"` instead of `'test.$stellentyp'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mb you want something like this?

```
return view('test.'.$stellentyp, ['typ' => $typ, 'stellentyp' => $stellentyp, 'bereich' => $bereich]);
```

change `'test.$stellentyp'` to `'test.'.$stellentyp` or `"test.$stellentyp"`

Comment: i test it but my route doesnt work.
Route::post('/$stellentyp', 'StartController@getValues')->name('user.$stellentyp');

Comment: @MonaMuhr How/why are routes involved now? That should be something like `Route::post('/stelle/{stellentyp}'...` https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters

Comment: Route::resource('user/start', 'StartController');
Route::post('user/'.$stellentyp,'StartController@getValues')->name('user.'.$stellentyp);

these are my routes

Comment: @MonaMuhr it should be like `Route::post('user/{stellentyp}','StartController@getValues')` i think

Comment: @MonaMuhr try to open `user/result` page after changes

Comment: @MonaMuhr I feel like you should open a new question regarding your routes. This one was about "_laravel view with a variable_".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$view = 'test.'.$stellentyp;
return view($view,['typ' => $typ, 'stellentyp', $stellentyp, 'bereich', $bereich]);
```

Comment: how should i change the route?

Comment: No need to change route just pass params